# How to modify chapter style in Memoir

Tags: macros, chapters, memoir

I'm using the **memoir class** and I have already styled my chapters as seen in the code and screenshot 1.

However, for some chapters that have longer titles I want the colours and spacing of the tikz boxes to differ and make the title text align properly when wrapping.

I can't seem to be able to override my default chapter style though for longer titles - I want to use a \newcommand named chapterLongerTitle (see screenshot 2 and code for \chapterLongerTitle). I've looked at multiple questions relating to this topic on stackexchange, but I couldn't get anywhere. Can anyone help please?

```
\usepackage{calc, xcolor, tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MY DEFAULT CHAPTER STYLING
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\ifNoChapNumber

\makeatletter\setlength\midchapskip{0pt}\makechapterstyle{myStyle}
{
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}      % erase default style
    \renewcommand\printchaptername{}    % erase default style
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{}     % erase default style
    \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Large\sffamily}
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
    
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
            \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);  
            \fill[red] (0,1.5) rectangle (0.5,1);  
            \fill[red] (1,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0);    
            \fill[red] (1,2) rectangle (0.5,1.5);    
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \ifNoChapNumber{ % if there is no chapter number
            \vspace*{-6.4em}\hspace*{3.4em}%
            \chaptitlefont\textcolor{purple}{##1} % chapter title
            \vspace*{2em}
        }
        \else{ % else, if there is a chapter number
            \vspace*{-9em}\hspace*{3.2em}%
            \chapnumfont\textcolor{red}{Chapter \thechapter} % chapter number
            
            \vspace*{0.5em}\hspace*{2.3em}%
            \chaptitlefont\textcolor{purple}{ ##1} % chapter title
            \vspace*{2em}
        }
        \fi
        \NoChapNumberfalse
    }
    \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\NoChapNumbertrue}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{myStyle}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STYLING FOR LONGER CHAPTER TITLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\chaptercopy\chapter % \let creates a backup of the original \chapter definition as \chaptercopy in this case
\newcommand\chapterLongerTitle[1]{\chaptercopy{#1}}{%
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
            \fill[yellow] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);  % bottom yellow square
            \fill[yellow] (0,2) rectangle (0.5,1.5);  % top yellow square
            \fill[blue] (1,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0);    % bottom blue square
            \fill[blue] (1,2.5) rectangle (0.5,2);     % top blue square
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace*{-9em}\hspace*{3.2em}%
        \chapnumfont\textcolor{red}{Chapter \thechapter} % chapter number
        \vspace*{0.5em}\hspace*{2.3em}%
        \chaptitlefont\textcolor{purple}{ #1} % chapter title
        \vspace*{2em}
    }
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOCUMENT BEGINS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
   \chapter{Introduction}
   \chapterLongerTitle{A two-line title goes here in but not aligning properly}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot 1:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Thanks

Comment: Better to use tikz to typeset the entire thing not just the decoration. When you have all these `\vspace` and `\hspace` it is a clear indicator that you are doing something wrong. Write the chapter title in a node anchored at `north west`, add `Chapter num` as another node relative to the first. Then add the decorations to locations relative to those two note boxes.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know I can do that with tikz. It's my first time using it. I'm reading this now https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package to get a better understanding of how tikz and nodes work. However, my current issue is that none of the changes inside \newcommand\chapterLongerTitle[1] appear in the document, and I don't understand why. None of them seem to override my original chapter styling, so I can't test what I've written in the new command.

Comment: I see no need for several chapter commands, see my answer below

Comment: It is an interesting design. If I may I might want to include it as an example in the memoir manual?

Comment: @daleif Yes of course. For context, I'm creating a PhD thesis template compatible with the [University of Essex](https://www.essex.ac.uk)'s style and branding. I'm planning to make this public (through GitHub) when I'm finished, and also pitch it to the university as an official template. I can let you know when the template is complete and uploaded on GitHub, if you would like to link to it.

Comment: That might be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, you have the right idea, it is just much easier to include everything into the `tikz` construction than to move things around to match the decorations

Edit: Added the `overlay` option to have the decoration take up no space and thus go into the margins. If not we get an overfull hbox because of the `\parbox` of text width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}*1
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{xcolor, tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MY DEFAULT CHAPTER STYLING
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\ifNoChapNumber

\makeatletter
\setlength\midchapskip{0pt}
\makechapterstyle{myStyle}
{
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}      % erase default style
    \renewcommand\printchaptername{}    % erase default style
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{}     % erase default style
    \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Large\sffamily}
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (title) at (0,0)
        {\parbox{\textwidth}{\raggedright\chaptitlefont ##1}};
        \coordinate (decobot) at (title.south west);
        \coordinate (decotop) at (title.north west);
        \ifNoChapNumber\else
        \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] (chapname) at
        ($(title.north west)+(0,0.2)$) {\chapnumfont\@chapapp~\thechapter};
        \coordinate (decotop) at (chapname.north west);
        \fi
        \def\DecoAdj{0.2}
        \coordinate (decotop) at ($(decotop)+(-\DecoAdj,\DecoAdj)$);
        \coordinate (decobot) at ($(decobot)+(-\DecoAdj,-\DecoAdj)$);
        \fill[red,overlay] (decotop) rectangle ++(-\DecoAdj,-\DecoAdj);
        \fill[red,overlay] (decotop) rectangle ++(\DecoAdj,\DecoAdj);
        \fill[red,overlay] (decobot) rectangle ++(\DecoAdj,-\DecoAdj);
        \fill[red,overlay] (decobot) rectangle ++(-\DecoAdj,\DecoAdj);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\NoChapNumbertrue}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{myStyle}


% just to show all 3 examples on one page
\let\clearforchapter\relax

\begin{document}
   \chapter{Introduction}
   \chapter{A two-line title goes here in but not aligning properly}
   \chapter*{No number}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm playing a bit around with your code to adapt it to my template. But the general idea works and it's very clear, thanks so much!